# Hiding of standard functions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, modern-experience, sharepoint-administration

Is it possible to hide the buttons "Share", "Upload", "Export to Excel" for the user?

[image: Buttons]

Above image shows the view when user is accessing document library.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you hide these standard functions, but you can **disable these standard functions by granting permission for users.**

**To Create a Custom Permission Level without Client Integration Features, follow these steps:**

1. Click on **Settings** Gear >> Choose "**Site Permissions**" link
2. Click "**Advanced permissions settings**" >> click on "**Permission Levels**" from the ribbon
3. Select any existing permission level such as **Contribute** or **Read** >> scroll to the bottom of the page >> click on "**Copy Permission level**" button
4. Provide a name to your new permission level. Under "**Site Permissions**", uncheck "**Use Client Integration Features  -  Use features which launch client applications. Without this permission, users will have to work on documents locally and upload their changes.**"

[image]

5. Click on "**Create**" button to create the permission level.
6. Grant the specific users this permission.This users cannot view  "**Export to Excel**" button, and cannot use "**Share**" button.

[image]

[image]